# why we using arrow and dot opertor only for user defined data types why not for primitive data types?

Tags: c++

I have question on why arrow and dot operator are used only for class,struct why not for primitive types? sorry if my question looks silly

Thanks

Comment: What would you want to do with these operators, for example, with integer objects?

Comment: What i tried to ask is why not we dereference 'p' (int *p;) with arrow operator?

Comment: That's a different question. Anyway, `*` is a _dereference_ operator, while `.` and `->` are _member-access_ operators. Why would you dereference a pointer with member-access operators? How would it look like? `p-> += 7;`? Moreover, if you had a pointer to a class instance and wanted to call a member function, would you like this syntax: `ptr->.f();`?

Comment: You can look at it this way: complex data types such as class or struct might hold more than one primitive (or complex) data types. So, in order to refer to a specific member of class or struct, you have to use dot or arrow operator. Primitive types hold only one value (directly), so in order to access primitive value it's enough to write its name (with no additional operators)

Answer (score 2):

Arrow and dot operators are used for accessing members. Primitive or fundamental data types don't have any members by their definition.
`struct`, `class` and `union` have concept of members. When we use object of these types no member fetching is required. When you need to access a member, `operator .` or `operator ->` is required.